# Script to set up Hadoop on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop

The script to setup Hadoop on EC2 as described in https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/AmazonEC2  has been removed from recent hadoop release. Google points me to  an alternative http://whirr.apache.org/ which also has been retired for more than a year.   Is there a replacement or alternative which is still good to set up the latest version of Hadoop on EC2?  Thank you!

**Update**

hadoop-ec2 script has been removed from hadoop src as on [01/11/2011](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/commit/f015768d3f86872861fd33d0945f28822bd1a7fb). The intention is to replace it by [Apache Whirr](https://whirr.apache.org/). It would be great if the removal could be explicitly documented. Unfortunately, early changelogs are no longer conveniently available on Hadoop official website.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than installing and maintaining Hadoop yourself on an Amazon EC2 instance, you could consider using the [Amazon EMR](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-what-is-emr.html) service.

Amazon EMR can automatically deploy a Hadoop cluster and can be triggered via the Management Console, an API call or the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/).